# How to provide certificate chain in SSLStream's AuthenticateAsServer()?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, https, mono

I'am implementing a SSL server in C#, using standard SSLStream.

Everything is fine so far, but - AuthenticateAsServer accepts only single certificate as parameter, while I have to provide the complete chain (3 of them).

I've built PKCS12 struct with all certificates (with help of Mono.Security), then call `new X509Certificate2(pkcs12.GetBytes())`, but nevertheless, only one is presented to the client.

So, the question is - how this could be done?

Thanks!

PS: I need a portable solution, which will work both in Mono and .NET on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is correct. The web server uses *only one* certificate with the `SslStream` (or anything else).

The certificate might be missing some information : The `Authority Information Access` extension of your server certificate shall point to the URI where the intermediary certificate will be downloaded.

Is this information missing ?

Comment: Well, actually, SslStream is able to send certificate chains (must be - this is what documentation says and it can be done in Microsoft.Net). Second, there is a bug in Mono which prevents this (apparently). Third, not all certificate extensions are supported by all SSL clients, unfortunately...